# Express this mathematically

Tags: functions, notation

Sorry it has been a while.  I have three variables, $X, Y, Z$.  Every $X$ has a different number of $Y$ and every $Y$ has a different number of $Z$ so how do I express the total number of $Z$?

For example, say you have people, who all have different number of shirts, which all have a different number of shirt buttons - how do you express the total number of buttons mathematically?

It is not just people $\times$ shirts $\times$  shirt buttons. What is it? Thanks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You let $a_{ij}$ be the number of buttons on the $j$th shirt of the $i$th person, and write $$\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}$$ for the total number of buttons.

Comment: How is this expressed in English?  Say someone asked you this question on the telephone and you had to say it rather than write it how would you say it?

Comment: "Sum on eye and jay of ay subscript eye jay."